# Make the get request to make post request

Tags: spring, post, model-view-controller, get, request

I need to make the get request to call below post func.

client make GET request (url: `http://domain/register1?username=userName&password=passWord&lastName=name&firstName=first`)

I want to make this to get method call func. but I could not create a normal **WebRequest** parameter. 
How I could make this to Get Request?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@Valid SignupForm form, BindingResult formBinding, WebRequest request) {

    if (formBinding.hasErrors()) {
        return null;
    }

    Account account = createAccount(form, formBinding);
    if (account != null) {
        SignInUtils.signin(account.getUsername());
        providerSignInUtils.doPostSignUp(account.getUsername(), request);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The spring function is only mapped for POST and will only accept that. Is there a special reason why you can't perform a POST request?

If you really want it to be GET, change the `method=RequestMethod.POST` to `method=RequestMethod.GET`

Comment: I know 'how to make the GET method call' but if I change this to GET, this function doesn't work. 'doPostSignUp(account.getUsername(), request);' because the request session is not normal. How could I make the normal request?

Answer (score 0):

Try delete method=RequestMethod.POST ( the defaul will be GET) or  change method=RequestMethod.POST to method=RequestMethod.GET. Besides, You can open browser console and type something (wihtout Session key)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

You can use Chrome Extension:
[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)